# JQuery validation stop form submission when there are errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am having trouble form Jquery Validation where the form is submitting even though though there are errors on the form.

I have checked out other solutions on here, but none of them have worked for me.

```
// validate.js file
function setupFormsValidation(formName){

    // validate
    $(formName).validate({
        onfocusout:false,
        onkeyup:false,
        onclick:false,
        focusInvalid: false,

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.parents('.inputgroup').length) {
                error.insertBefore(element.parents('.inputgroup'));
                element.parents('.inputgroup').addClass('error');
            } else {
                error.insertBefore(element);
            };            
        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

            // Code to process errors

    });

    // Code for initializing the form etc


};  //setupFormsValidation
```

On my form, here is the code:

```
    <form action="thankyou.php" class="frmValidate" id="change-dept-form" method="post" name="change-dept-form">
        <fieldset class="inlinelabels">
        <legend><br /> Department name and code change information</legend>
        <div class="row required" id="txt_current_dept_code_row">
            <label class="required" for="txt_current_dept_code">Current department code (3 characters min, 4 characters max):</label> 
            <input class="required" data-min-length="3" id="txt_current_dept_code" name="txt_current_dept_code" required="required" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="row required" id="faculty2_row">
            <label for="faculty2">Faculty:</label>
                <select class="required" id="faculty2" name="faculty2" required="required">
                    <option value="">- Select -</option>
                    <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
                    <option value="Business">Business</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="row buttons">
            <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
        </div>
    </form>

<script src="../../assets/js/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    setupFormsValidation('#change-dept-form');

    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){

       $form = $('#change-dept-form');

        if ($form.valid()){
            alert('Test'); 
            // need code to submit

        } else {
            alert('Show errors');
        };    

    });

});
```

I have point a breakpoint on the if ($form.valid()){ and it doesn't run any code after that. It doesn't show even show the Test alert or the Show Errors alert.

Answer (score 0):

You're not cancelling the submit and that's why it takes place no matter if there are errors or not. You need to cancel the default behavior for the submit button when there are errors

```
} else {
    alert('Show errors');
    return false; // <-- This should do the trick
};
```

Comment: @Moxie C: I'm afraid that's not possible. Please be sure that return false is executed;

Comment: I have used firebug to debug and put the breakpoint on on the code and it doesn't even get to the alert('Show errors) part of the code

Comment: @Moxie C: I thought that the alert was triggered. What happens if you add `return false` as very first line of the method. Do you see the error messages on the screen?

Comment: @Moxie C: could you check the browser console to see if there is any error?

Comment: @Moxie C: you say that the code stop executing on `if ($form.valid())``... that seems to indicate an error. Please confirm if you're sure that after executing that line nothing else is executed. Also, it seems you could create a [jsFilddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show your problem.

Comment: I found the problem as there was a problem in my validator code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick: false` option disables validation when the submit button is clicked.  This is why your form is being submitted without validation.